# Can not fetch the complete file from nginx with http.Get in GO

Tags: http, get, go

I have written a function that uses http.Get() to fetch files from the Nginx server (which is on the same host as the one fetching files just for test). The code is like this:

```
res,err := http.Get(addr)  // addr is the file address on Nginx server
defer res.Body.Close()

for {
    v := &vFile{path,0}    // path is the file path to write
    bv :=bufio.NewWriterSize(v,1024*1024)  // Write 1MB each time
    _, err:= io.Copy(bv,res.Body)
    if err == nil { err = bv.Flush() }
}
```

with vFile and the Write function defined like

```
type vFile struct {
    path string
    cur int64
}
func (wtr *vFile) Write(buf []byte) {
    var f *os.File
    if wtr.cur == 0 { f,wtr.err = os.Create(wtr.path) }
    else { f,wtr.err = os.OpenFile(wtr.path,os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND,0666) }
    _, err := f.WriteAt(buf,twr.path)
}
```

However, in high concurrency situation (for example, the concurrency number is 500), a large number of files are not fully fetched, and in Nginx log the HTTP response is 200 while the file length is not correct:

```
"GET /videos/4b42d6e8e138233c7eb62939.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 37863424 "-" "Go 1.1 package http" "-"
```

The file has a size of 75273523 Bytes while only 37863424 Bytes are fetched. If I change the size from 1MB to 32KB, the situation can be much better, but there is still a few files that is not complete. So what might be wrong with the code?

Comment: Your second code sample doesn't look valid -- your type's `Write` method doesn't match the `Writer` interface for a start.  Also, is there any reason why you don't just hold the file you're writing to open until you've received all the data?

Answer (score 1):

In this function you aren't closing the `os.File`. I suspect that is why it is going wrong.

```
func (wtr *vFile) Write(buf []byte) {
    var f *os.File
    if wtr.cur == 0 { f,wtr.err = os.Create(wtr.path) }
    else { f,wtr.err = os.OpenFile(wtr.path,os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND,0666) }
    _, err := f.WriteAt(buf,twr.path)
}
```

If not post a complete compiling gofmt-ed example!